# What is the best way to get windows full name from go?

Tags: go

In Windows, I can run something like `systeminfo | findstr /C:"OS Name` to output the Windows full name to the console. I've tried a couple different variations of piping output from one command to the other, but I just get empty strings.

**Example**

```
first := exec.Command("systeminfo")
second := exec.Command("findstr /C:'OS Name'")

reader, writer := io.Pipe()

first.Stdout = writer
second.Stdin = reader

var buffer bytes.Buffer
second.Stdout = &buffer

first.Start()
second.Start()
first.Wait()
writer.Close()
second.Wait()

output := buffer.String()

log.Printf("output: %s", output)
```

`

Are there any built in methods to get this information?

Comment: Do you need the OS name, or are you just trying to parse it for version info? (There's `syscall.GetVersion` for the latter)

Comment: The OS name, for example `Windows Server 2012 R2 Datacenter`

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to use the [golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry) package.

A simple example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/sys/windows/registry"
)

func main() {
    key, _ := registry.OpenKey(registry.LOCAL_MACHINE, `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion`, registry.QUERY_VALUE) // error discarded for brevity
    defer key.Close()
    productName, _, _ := key.GetStringValue("ProductName") // error discarded for brevity
    fmt.Println(productName)
}
```

This prints `Windows 8.1 Pro` on my computer.